# Search for Facebook statuses with certain words

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search

I'm trying to make a desktop app wich can search for statuses containing certain words from the posts/statuses made by the people who are friends of the user who's using it. I managed to authenticate it and to get the user access token (if this can help), so I have no problems about the authentication process.

The problem is: what's the URL I need to use to search for those statuses containing those words? I tried to look for a solution in the internet and in Stack Overflow, but with no success.

I also already have the permission to see their (friends) statuses.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't allow you to easily do this. They simply don't give developers these options because they want to limit data mining applications - applications that simply extract as much data as they can.

What you will have to do is extract all the posts and statuses for all the friends of the user and then manually scan through them for the keywords you are searching for. This is an intensive process and you will be making **a lot** of requests to Facebook.

Comment: therefore getting flagged as some sort of spammer :D
this can be done with public posts and statuses though, so I suppose that there must be a way!

Comment: No - you are talking about public data.  Friends data is by no means public.

Comment: I know, that's what I meant :)